# Trying to get the element from a tag after its been updated

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am currently trying to get the values from a element tag after my html tag 
"main" has been updated by my java script code to include the html values in another php file.

```
  <main> 
       <?php include 'index.php'; ?>
  </main>

     <div id="footer">
     </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="homepage_J.js"></script>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="homepage_A.js"></script>-->

    </body>
  </html>
```

Above is the relevant part of my php  file that contain the html body. My java script code should change the current value of the  tag then scan to get certain values of the the newly loaded file.

here is the javascript.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

 $(window).on('hashchange', function(){
     var pageHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
     console.log("page hash: "+pageHash);

     if( pageHash.length==0){
        pageHash = "index";
      }

     $('main').load(pageHash + ".php", pageFunctions() );
  });  

  $("nav a").on('click', function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      var page = $(this).attr("href");
      console.log("Loading " + page);
      window.location.hash = formatForHash(page);
      $('main').load(page, pageFunctions());

  });



  $(window).trigger('hashchange',pageFunctions());


});




function pageFunctions() {
    var current_page =  $("#page").text(); //checks to see which file called the javascript



       // Switch case that will load appropriate function based on the file loaded(homepage)
  switch(current_page){
      case "INDEX":
               console.log("HOME loaded");
               break;
      case "INBOX":
               console.log("INBOX loaded");
               break;
      case "REGISTRATION":
              console.log("REGIS loaded");
              break;
      case "COMPOSE":
              compose();
              console.log("compose loaded");
              break;
      default:
              console.log("ERROR IN :" + current_page );
              break;
  }
}

function formatForHash (page)
{
   var hash = page.split('.');
   return hash[0];
}
```

The console logs were used to help me debug he code. And what i am getting from it is that javascript is return the element form the previous load to main rather than the current values that is loaded to it(what im seeing is not what i am getting).

so the value in *var current_page* Isn't the page that i am currently on. Its not corresponding. so if i leave from index to compose the value in it is "index", and the reverese would give me a value of "compose".

so my question is how would i get the values of the elements that are currently on the page, after or before a load.

sorry for the lengthy post hopefully i gave it enough detail.

Comment: what you need are delegates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('main').load(page, pageFunctions());
```

You are immediately executing pageFunctions rather than giving it as a callback.  Take off the `()` so it will be used as a callback when the load finishes.

Comment: Thanks that solved everything. Initially I was moving around the function call .